# How to use apply functions correctly when there are NA values

Tags: r, dplyr, apply, na, mapply

I'd like to calculate a function on multiple columns of a dataframe with random NA values. I have two questions:

1. How to deal with NAs? The code runs when I try it on non-NA columns, but returns `NA` when there are NAs even though I remove them.
2. How to print the results in a dataframe format instead of multiple arrays? I used `mapply` but it doesn't seem to do the calculations correctly.

Here is my code:

```
#create a data frame with random NAs
df<-data.frame(category1 = sample(c(1:10),100,replace=TRUE),
           category2 = sample(c(1:10),100,replace=TRUE)
)
insert_nas <- function(x) {
   len <- length(x)
   n <- sample(1:floor(0.2*len), 1)
   i <- sample(1:len, n)
   x[i] <- NA 
   x
}
df <- sapply(df, insert_nas) %>% as.data.frame()
df$type <- sample(c("A", "B", "C"),100,replace=TRUE)


#using apply:
library(NPS)
apply(df[,c('category1', 'category2')], 2, 
   function(x) df %>% filter(!is.na(x)) %>% group_by(type) %>%
   transmute(nps(x)) %>% unique()
)
#results:
$category1
# A tibble: 3 x 2
# Groups:   type [3]
type  `nps(x)`
<chr>    <dbl>
1 B           NA
2 A           NA
3 C           NA
...

#using mapply
mapply(function(x) df %>% filter(!is.na(x)) %>% group_by(type) %>%
   transmute(nps(x)) %>% unique(), df[,c('category1', 'category2')])

#results:
       category1   category2  
type   Character,3 Character,3
nps(x) Numeric,3   Numeric,3
```

Regarding the function I use, it doesn't have a built in way to deal with NAs, so I remove NAs prior to calling it.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend reading the "Programming with `dplyr`" vignette. `apply` is made for matrices, `dplyr` is made for data frames, and you're trying to combine the two, while also passing in individual columns...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still used the `!is.na` part of your code because it seems that nps can't deal with `NA`, even though the documentation said it should (possible bug). I changed your `apply` to `lapply` and passed the variables as the list. Then I used `get` to identify the variable name that appears in quotes as a variable in your `df`.

```
df<-data.frame(category1 = sample(c(1:10),100,replace=TRUE),
               category2 = sample(c(1:10),100,replace=TRUE)
)
insert_nas <- function(x) {
  len <- length(x)
  n <- sample(1:floor(0.2*len), 1)
  i <- sample(1:len, n)
  x[i] <- NA 
  x
}
df <- sapply(df, insert_nas) %>% as.data.frame()
df$type <- sample(c("A", "B", "C"),100,replace=TRUE)


#using apply:
library(NPS)
df2 <- as.data.frame(lapply(c('category1', 'category2'),  
      function(x) df %>% filter(!is.na(get(x))) %>% group_by(type) %>%
        transmute(nps(get(x))) %>% unique()
),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

colnames(df2) <- c("type", "nps_cat1","type2","nps_cat2")
#type2 is redundant
df2 <- select(df2, -type2)
```

Comment: test to see if `nps` can handle `NA`s: `nps(c(1:10,NA))` vs `nps(c(1:10))`

Comment: This worked! thanks! And `no nps(c(1:10,NA))` returns `NA`.

Comment: please update your answer to `as.data.frame(lapply(...))` so it answers my second question too.

Comment: @Ana I updated the post and cleaned up the output a bit. Yes, I realize that `nps(c(1:10,NA))` returns `NA` - but it shouldn't according to the documentation.